# how to get adjacency matrix where values are the difference of nodes' attributes

Tags: r, igraph

I have a network like this:

```
g1 <- erdos.renyi.game(10, 0.5)
V(g1)$time <- seq(1:10)
```

I know that igraph has a get.adjacency() to retrieve an adjacency matrix from a graph, where values in the matrix are either 0 (no link) or 1 (a link is present), or this value can be one out of every edge attributes available... I have to retrieve an adjacency matrix, but instead of the traditional 0/1 value or the edge attribute, I need to have the difference of $time between the sender and the receiver of each dyad:

```
adj <- get.adjacency(g1)
dims <- dim(adj)
for(i in 1:dims[1]){
    for(ii in 1:dims[2]){
    adj[i,ii] <- (V(g1)[V(g1)==i]$time - V(g1)[V(g1)==ii]$time)
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you are calculating in your loop is not the adjacency matrix, but the weighted distance of the shortest path. Anyway, the way to do either of these operations is to add a weight attribute to the edges, which represents the difference in times. This is then much easier to deal with than the attributes of the vertices. Here's an idea:

```
# your code
require(igraph)
g1 <- erdos.renyi.game(10, 0.5)
V(g1)$time <- 1:10
# adding a weight (difference in times)
E(g1)$weight <- apply(get.edgelist(g1), 1, function(i){
  abs(V(g1)$time[i[1]]-V(g1)$time[i[2]])
})
# calculate adjacency and/or shortest path. 
get.adjacency(g1, attr="weight")
shortest.paths(g1)
```

**EDIT** It seems that the difference you would like to calculate has nothing to do with the graph at all. You are probably just looking for `outer`:

```
outer(V(g1)$time, V(g1)$time, "-")
```

Comment: thank you, but I think I didn't clearly stated my point: I need this difference calculated for all dyads. If you consider the edges, then for not connected nodes such value won't be calculated..

Comment: another function I ignored, never happens with R... :)

Comment: The first solution is OK, although you do not need `apply`, just subtract the second column from the first, it is much faster. R has vector operations. The `outer` solution is very bad in terms of speed because its time complexity is O(n^2), instead of the optimal O(m).

Answer (score 0):

It is actually easier to work with the edge list in this case:

```
require(igraph)
require(Matrix)
g1 <- erdos.renyi.game(10, 0.5)
V(g1)$time <- 1:10

el <- get.edgelist(g1)
sparseMatrix(el[,1], el[,2], x=abs(el[,1]-el[,2]),
             dims=rep(vcount(g1), 2), symmetric=TRUE)
# 10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"

#  [1,] . 1 2 3 . 5 6 . . .
#  [2,] 1 . 1 . 3 4 5 6 7 8
#  [3,] 2 1 . 1 2 3 4 . 6 7
#  [4,] 3 . 1 . . 2 . . 5 .
#  [5,] . 3 2 . . . 2 3 4 .
#  [6,] 5 4 3 2 . . . . . 4
#  [7,] 6 5 4 . 2 . . 1 . .
#  [8,] . 6 . . 3 . 1 . 1 .
#  [9,] . 7 6 5 4 . . 1 . .
# [10,] . 8 7 . . 4 . . . .
```

Comment: Gabor, as stated above in the comments, I need this difference calculated for all dyads. If you consider the edges, then for not connected nodes such value won't be calculated... thus the outer proposal by @shadow

Comment: You said: "I need to have the difference of $time between the sender and the receiver of each link." I would have never thought that a missing edge is a "link". Anyway, if you need all pairs of vertices, then you cannot do better than `outer`.

Comment: my bad, just edited my question to be "between the sender and the receiver of each dyad"